# How can I extract a chain of digits before the text ".html"?

Tags: python, regex

I have a hard time finding a regular expression to extract a chain of digits (e.g. 56478888) from a URL. Input examples:

```
http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html#his
http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html
http://wwww.example/f-1234565-56478888.html
```

As you can see, sometimes there are characters before the chain of digits and sometimes there are characters after ".html".

The regular expression I came up with is the following:

```
re.compile(".*?/f\-\d+\-(\d+)\.html")
```

But it doesn't match all cases. How can I fix my regex?

Comment: Maybe you can post more examples? To find a pattern to match, we'll need several versions, to find the one that's good enough for your problem

Comment: You don't have to match the string in full. Instead only match the part that you care about. For example if you want to match the digits before `.html` simply use something like `\d+(?=\.html)`. If you know that there are exactly 8 digits, use `\d{8}(?=\.html)`. This is using a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you all. As the number of digits may change \d+(?=\.html) is more appropriate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the second group of numbers you could use findall:

```
import re

urls = ["http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html#his",
        "http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html",
        "http://wwww.example/f-1234565-56478888.html"]

pattern = re.compile("\d+")
print([matches[-1] for matches in map(pattern.findall, urls)])
```

**Output**

```
['56478888', '56478888', '56478888']
```

The pattern `"\d+"` simply matches all group of digits. As an alternative you could search for the group of digits just before `".html"`:

```
pattern = re.compile("(\d+)\.html")
print([match.group(1) for match in map(pattern.search, urls)])
```

**Output**

```
['56478888', '56478888', '56478888']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern `r"\d{8}"`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = ["http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html#his", "http://wwww.example/f-1234565-auc56478888.html", "http://wwww.example/f-1234565-56478888.html"]

for i in s:
    print(re.findall(r"\d{8}", i))    #8 digits
```

**Output:**

```
['56478888']
['56478888']
['56478888']
```